# Eclipse: saved LaunchConfiguration overrides LaunchType

Tags: java, launch, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse

Not sure if it will be Eclipse or Eclipse-plugin-dev answer.

In [open-source Nodeclipse](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1) project [plugin.xml defines that .coffee file can be launched](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/plugin.xml#L57-235)  as `coffee`, `coffee --compile` or `Node with monitor` (There are [3 defined LaunchShortcuts](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/src/org/nodeclipse/debug/launch)).

First time it work fine, but then consequent launches only repeat previous LaunchType. I have found that deleting saved LaunchConfiguration (from Run -> Run Configurations) will let it run again (and then only as this type again)

The code in question is [LaunchShortcut](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/src/org/nodeclipse/debug/launch/LaunchShortcut.java#L71-107) (see snippet below), however there is no any `if` checking, so this behavior should be deeper in Eclipse org.eclipse.debug module.

**How can saved LaunchConfiguration override LaunchType ?**

```
/**
* Launch an file,using the file information, which means using default
* launch configurations.
*
* @param file
* @param mode
*/
private void launchFile(IFile file, String mode) throws CoreException {
    // check for an existing launch config for the file
    String path = file.getFullPath().toString();
    ILaunchManager launchManager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
    ILaunchConfigurationType type = launchManager.getLaunchConfigurationType(Constants.LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_TYPE_ID);
    ILaunchConfiguration configuration = createLaunchConfiguration(type, path, file);
    DebugUITools.launch(configuration, mode);
    // then execution goes in LaunchConfigurationDelegate.java launch() method
}

/**
* Create a new configuration and set useful data.
*
* @param type
* @param path
* @param file
* @return
* @throws CoreException
*/

private ILaunchConfiguration createLaunchConfiguration(ILaunchConfigurationType type, String path, IFile file) throws CoreException {
 String configname = file.getFullPath().toString().replace('/', '-');
 if(configname.startsWith("-")) {
 configname = configname.substring(1);
 }

 ILaunchConfiguration[] configs = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunchConfigurations(type);
 for(ILaunchConfiguration config : configs) {
 if(configname.equals(config.getName())) {
 return config;
 }
 }

 // create a new configuration for the file
    ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy workingCopy = type.newInstance(null, configname);
    workingCopy.setAttribute(Constants.KEY_FILE_PATH, path);
    setMoreAttributes(workingCopy);
    return workingCopy.doSave();
}

protected void setMoreAttributes(ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy workingCopy) {
// stub for extension
}
```

Help! The code snippet is maybe not enough to answer the question, but references files and everything is in Github repository. The question was raised, because I am not sure if it is possible at all to have many Run Configuration for the same file. Then code snippets doesn't matter at all.

Update: Looking after a while at [plugin.xml defines that .coffee file can be launched](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/plugin.xml#L57-235) , I noticed that I am actually using the same `<configurationType
                id= "org.nodeclipse.debug.launch.LaunchConfigurationType" >` in all 5 cases. However adding unique LaunchConfigurationType id for every launch makes no difference.

Comment: What have you tryed until now? ist it an option to override the default launch configure file?

Comment: Do you mean on file system level? Find where Eclipse stores that data, and delete those files? hmm... Yes, it is idea.

Comment: Problem delete wont solve cos there is a default config to rebuild them in case of deleted data, what I meant is find the default config file and make the change inside it, therefore u wont lose the data cos the file is already created

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly do you mean. Could you please add answer, so discussion would go under it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the launch configuration with this:

[Creating a Java application launch configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm)

Launch groups can also be setle with this help:

[Launch Group](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_run_dbg_launch_group.htm)

Until here Im pretty sure you have knowledge about, so lets keep moving; You can have different launch configuration for the same file, thats handled with the launch group tool, what I dont get is if you want those different configuration for the same environment or not.

Also here [Launch Configuration Types](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_debug_core_launchConfigurationTypes.html) and here [Adding launchers to the platform](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/debug_launch_adding.htm) you cand find information about the struct of the launch type file

To finish here [Interface ILaunchConfigurationTabGroup](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/ui/ILaunchConfigurationTabGroup.html) is the interface of the launch type tab group;

My Suggestion in codelines:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchConfigurationTabGroups">
   <launchConfigurationTabGroup 

        <"launchConfigurationType1"

        <"/launchConfigurationType1"> 

             <"launchConfigurationType2"

             <"/launchConfigurationType2">

       //and so on... 

   </launchConfigurationTabGroup>
 </extension>
```

Comment: This is my plugin.xml https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/plugin.xml

It defines 2 launches for .coffee, the similar for .js but in several plugin.xml files.

The problem is that Eclipse remembers what launch was used first time, and ignores whatever launch was used afterwards.

Comment: I still dont get why bother at all, I mean, If you first file works the way you want whats the problem then? Do you need to change it "dinamcally" (each time you open)? or you want to create a feature like this?

Comment: Let's say there are .js files that are Node.js application.
They can be run with `node` executable or some monitor like `forever`
The problem that after 1st launch Launch type is fixed.

Or think about .js files in general that can run with node, mozilla rhino, java 8 nashorn and others JS engines.